# Checking for consecutive dates and excluding odd entries

Tags: r

**Edited! See text below**

I am trying create a for loop whilst using dplyr and I seem to be missing something.
A simplified version of what I am doing is trying to do is represented in the code below.

```
> df
                    user_id                         var x
1                   1                               a
2                   1                               b
3                   1                               c
4                   2                               d
5                   2                               e
6                   2                               f
```

I am trying to filter out the data for user number 1 and then create a for loop for my further analysis.

```
df %>%
    filter(user_id==1)%>%
    for(i in 1:nrow()) {
        print(i)
        }
```

However, I keep getting the same message:

```
Error in function_list[[k]](value) : object 'i' not found
```

I would expect for the nrow() function to just pass my transformed df as a variable, but apparently that's not the case. I've also tried just passing df in nrow() and seeing how it reacts, but I get the same message.
I am still an R beginner, so I am probably missing something simple. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

---

**EDITED**:
Since simplifying the question seems to render it more confusing, I'll just lay out my problem.
So, I have reported days of menstruation in a subset of users and I want to clean my data.

```
> df

    user_id    menstruation_date"
1     1          20160602
2     1          20160603
3     1          20160604
4     1          20160605
5     1          20160606
6     1          20160712
7     1          20160909
8     1          20160910
9     1          20160911
10    1          20160912
11    1          20160913
12    6          20160121
13    6          20160122
14    6          20160123
15    6          20160221
```

Let's consider user 1. From the 2nd of June to the 6th of June 2016, user 1 reports having her period. I would like to group this under one cycle.
But then look at line 6, where she only reports one day, in July. Since it is unlikely for menstruation to last one single day, I want to exclude this entry from my analysis and not consider this cycle.
I was trying to solve this problem by creating a for loop that would check for consecutive days and consider only cycles where at least 3 consecutive menstruation days are present.

For the sample I pasted above, the desired output for user 1 would be:

```
> df

    user_id    menstruation_date"
1     1          20160602
2     1          20160603
3     1          20160604
4     1          20160605
5     1          20160606
6     1          20160909
7     1          20160910
8     1          20160911
9     1          20160912
10    1          20160913
```

Where the odd entry on row 6 (discussed above), has been removed.

I would ultimately want to do this for every user.

I hope this longer text renders the question clearer. Thanks!

Comment: If could share your larger objective, it'd be easy to help you out!

Comment: Changed the question to answer your comment!

Comment: Please check the answer and hope it helps!

Comment: Had to do some reading to fully understand what you did. It seems to work! Thank you for helping me out and teaching me so many new tricks at the same time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a combination `mutate` from `dplyr` to do this. But someone could write a better solution for this!

```
df <- read.table(text = "user_id    date
1     1          20160602
2     1          20160603
3     1          20160604
4     1          20160605
5     1          20160606
6     1          20160712
7     1          20160909
8     1          20160910
9     1          20160911
10    1          20160912
11    1          20160913
12    6          20160121
13    6          20160122
14    6          20160123
15    6          20160221", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)


#df$date <- strptime(df$date,format ='%Y%m%d') 

df$date <- lubridate::ymd(df$date)

newdf <- df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% mutate(days = date - lag(date, default = NA)) %>%  
  mutate(days = ifelse(is.na(days),0,days)) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse( days + lead(days, default = 0) > days + 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(ifelse(flag + lag(flag, default = TRUE) == 2, FALSE, TRUE)) %>%
  select (user_id, date)

newdf

> newdf
# A tibble: 14 x 2
# Groups:   user_id [2]
   user_id       date
     <int>     <date>
 1       1 2016-06-02
 2       1 2016-06-03
 3       1 2016-06-04
 4       1 2016-06-05
 5       1 2016-06-06
 6       1 2016-09-09
 7       1 2016-09-10
 8       1 2016-09-11
 9       1 2016-09-12
10       1 2016-09-13
11       6 2016-01-21
12       6 2016-01-22
13       6 2016-01-23
14       6 2016-02-21
>
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using dplyr filter is to eliminate for loops.
So, to get what you want just use:

```
df %>% filter(user_id==1)


 user_id var_x
1       1     a
2       1     b
3       1     c
```

Answer (score 0):

After using @amrrs 's answer, I extended the data cleaning. "menstruation" is my data set (substitute for df in the solutions above) and "beginn_local_date" the date when period was reported. Here is the code:

```
#Cleaning data: exclude female users with non-reliable information
    ##formating dates
menstruation$begin_local_date <- lubridate::ymd(menstruation$begin_local_date)

    ##Each cycle has to have at least 3 days
        ###Stackoverflow solution: thank you amrrs!
new_mens <- menstruation %>% 
    group_by(user_id) %>% 
    mutate(days = begin_local_date - lag(begin_local_date, default = NA)) %>%  
    mutate(days = ifelse(is.na(days),0,days)) %>%
    mutate(flag = ifelse(days + lead(days, default = 0) > days + 1, 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(ifelse(flag + lag(flag, default = TRUE) == 2, FALSE, TRUE)) %>%
    filter(days<2 | days>=21)%>% #if 2 included, then one forgotten day in otherwise full cycle won't be forgotten
    mutate(daysagain=ifelse(days<2,days,0)) %>%
    mutate(group=0)

    #mutate(day.idx2=ifelse(is.na(day.idx),(lag(day.idx2,default=0)+1),1))
count<-0

for (i in 1:length(new_mens$daysagain)) {
    if (new_mens$daysagain[i]==0) {
        count <- count+1
        new_mens$group[i] <- count
    } else {
        new_mens$group[i] <- count
    }
}

new_mens<-new_mens %>%
    group_by(user_id,group) %>%
    mutate(total.per.group=n()) %>%
    filter(total.per.group>=3) %>%
    mutate(helper=1) %>%
    mutate(our.idx=cumsum(helper)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    mutate(total.per.user = n()) %>% 
    filter(total.per.user>=9) %>%
    select(user_id, begin_local_date, days, our.idx)%>%
    ungroup()
```

The result is a more clean dataset with each day in a cycle being indexed:

```
> new_mens
   user_id begin_local_date  days our.idx
     <int>           <date> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       1       2016-06-02     0       1
 2       1       2016-06-03     1       2
 3       1       2016-06-04     1       3
 4       1       2016-06-05     1       4
 5       1       2016-06-06     1       5
 6       1       2016-09-09    59       1
 7       1       2016-09-10     1       2
 8       1       2016-09-11     1       3
 9       1       2016-09-12     1       4
10       1       2016-09-13     1       5
```